# xcode7.1.1 not opening in El Capitan

Tags: xcode

when I run /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode  from commandline it shows
2015-11-26 22:04:26.876 Xcode[1176:56924] ### Failed to load Addressbook class CNContactNameFormatter
2015-11-26 22:04:27.263 Xcode[1176:56948]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/Chaitanya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%207.1.1.db).

and remains in the same state and after some time xcode icon disappears

Comment: Xcode appears in launchpad and disappears after some time..i also tried re installing

Answer (score 1):

Don't launch Xcode that way.  Use `open /Applications/Xcode.app`.

Comment: It sounds like you have a corrupted install.  Perhaps try repairing permissions in Disk Utility.

Comment: when i right click on Xcode in launchpad in open developer tools it is not showing IDE .but it opens files (xml,java etc)

Answer (score -3):

Delete `/Users/xubo/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin`. Then restart your computer. Next, open your project and select load Bundle.

Comment: I am sorry answer this question . But when you happen this mistake (file:///Users/Chaitanya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%207.1.1.db),you  can try this answer to solution.